# I don't know why I can't see the total number of words in this doc from this program

Tags: python

```
# Open the file in read mode with specified encoding
with open("Python-wiki.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    # Read the content of the file
    content = file.read()

# Split the content into words
words = content.split()

# Create an empty dictionary
word_frequencies = {}

# Iterate over each word and update its frequency
for word in words:
    if word in word_frequencies:
        word_frequencies[word] += 1
    else:
        word_frequencies[word] = 1

# Print the word frequencies
for word, frequency in word_frequencies.items():
    print(f"{word}: {frequency}")
```

Why can't I execute the problems?

Comment: Where did you expect this program to show you the total number of words in the document?

Comment: What is inside `Python-wiki.txt`?

Comment: the code is setup to retrieve a dictionary with a word count. you could sum all the frequenceis to the the total number of words.

Comment: What *exactly* were you expecting to see? What *exactly* is it doing instead of what you expect? This feels like a problem of expectations, not behavior, and you haven't provided the relevant parts of a [MCVE] for us to help you. Side-note: Your counting code could be *dramatically* simplified, and sped up, by `collections.Counter`, with all but the printing code simplified down to: `with open("Python-wiki.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    word_frequencies = collecitons.Counter(file.read().split())`

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize NumPy's `.unique` function with `return_counts=True` to efficiently find all of the words in a document as well as their frequency.

```py
import numpy as np

def count_word_frequencies(text):
    words = text.split()
    unique_words, counts = np.unique(words, return_counts=True)
    word_frequencies = dict(zip(unique_words, counts))

    return word_frequencies
```

Example:

```py
>>> count_word_frequencies("hello how are you today today")
{'are': 1, 'hello': 1, 'how': 1, 'today': 2, 'you': 1}
```

It may also be beneficial to preprocess the text by removing non-alphanumeric characters and lowercasing it, preventing the function from treating `Hello,`, `hello.` and `hello` as different words.

Answer (score 0):

the code is setup to retrieve a dictionary with a word count. you can sum all the frequenceis (in the dict) to get the total number of words.

to achieve this, you could use the following function:

```py
def sum_dict_values(dict):
  """
  Sums the values in a given dict.

  Args:
    dict: The dict to sum the values of.

  Returns:
    The sum of the values in the dict.
  """
  sum_ = 0
  for key, value in dict.items():
    sum_ += value
  return sum_
```